# Elastic Beanstalk .ebextentsion - how to make it default to TLSv1.2

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

Linux 2 for Elastic Beanstalk written in Java

Below is my .platform/nginx/conf.d/https.conf file.   When I run this, my Load Balancer defaults to ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08.  I only want ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01 selected when I do this.  What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name  localhost;
   server_tokens off;

   access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_access.log main;

   # access_log off;
   # ssl                  on;
   ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

   ssl_session_timeout  5m;

   ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2;   
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

   location /subd {
      proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8443/subd;
      proxy_set_header   Connection "";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

}
```

Comment: If you have load balancer, why do you use SSL on your instances? This is rarely done in practice.

Comment: I don't understand your response.  My code provided is pretty much exactly like all the examples I see on the Internet.   So how is it done differently?    Regarding my initial question, can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with the load balancer, yes.

On EB, I had SSL terminating at the ELB though not on the server (80=>instance:80, 443=>instance:8443). The solution was as follows (credit fully to the author of this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kungl/2e2268ba8ccd59185e7fe50c2732d447)).

Current named policies for [classic load balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-policy-table.html) are on AWS' site.

Create a new file `.ebextension/change-elb-tls-policy.config`

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elb:policies:tlspolicy
    option_name: LoadBalancerPorts 
    value: 443    
  - namespace: aws:elb:policies:tlspolicy
    option_name: SSLReferencePolicy
    value: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01
```